# SimpleDateFormat always returns all dates

Tags: android, string, date, simpledateformat

I have a `JSON` that get a `Date` as `dd-mm-yyyy`, but I need convert that `String` to `Date`, but when I do the `SimpleDateFormat` always returns `Sat May 02 00:00:00 EDT 2015` (for example) and I want `02-05-2015`

this is my code:

```
String str = city.getString("bd_fecha");
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                date = dateFormat.parse(str); //// DATE ALWAYS RETURNS Sat May 02 00:00:00 EDT 2015(for example)
```

Comment: what is the value of str?

Comment: the response of JSON, DATE of a MYSQL query, it returns 10-08-2015 (for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, after parse you have to format also

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dateInString = "07-06-2013";

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(str))` returns a String and date is a Date

Comment: @AitorRamosPajares Have updated the answer, i confirmed its working properly

Comment: yes `formatter.format(date)` returns 07-06-2013 but it's a String and I need a Date

Comment: in date object it will always return you 'Fri Jun 07 00:00:00 MYT 2013' and not '07-06-2013'

Comment: and how can I order a list of String with format 07-06-2013

Comment: you can order is using date object and while displaying u can format it